# Mysql Update throws Error 1175

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to insert some rows in a table using MySQL 5.7 with MySQL Workbench 6.2.
When I try it I get the error 1175 (update without WHERE in safe update mode)

My query has a WHERE clause in it is filtering the PK of the table too.

This is how it looks:

```
> update inventory as inv
> 
> set   inv.fk_location          = null
>     , inv.location_description = null
> 
> -- only buffered rows 
> where inv.id_inventory in (
>     select tmp.id_inventory   
>     from tmp_inventory_location as tmp )
```

The subselect gives two rows with two inventory_id's which are also in the table I want to update.  The field id_inventory is also the primary key with the settings UN AI PK.
So as far as I googled it everything should be ok. Or am I missing one thing?
I would really dislike to change the safe update mode for that query.

Thanks
Felix

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step. This might help:

1. Go to Edit then preferences
2. Go to **SQL Queries** Tab and uncheck the **Safe Updates** Then reconnect.